# Clone element form

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to unsuccessfully duplicate form items

Hello everyone.
I have a form and I need a button to duplicate fields every time the user clicks.
My form:

```
<v-layout v-for="(phone, index) in people.phones" :key="index" row
                                          wrap>
 <v-flex md7>
   <v-text-field v-model="phone.number" label="Phone number*" required>
 </v-text-field>
</v-flex>

<v-flex md5 class="pl-3">
 <v-select v-model="phone.type" :rules="phone.tipoRules" required
                                                  :items="['WhatsApp', 'Commercial', 'Home']" label="Phone type*">
</v-select>
 </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: Please provide more informations: What have you tried so far (sample code), where are you getting an error. I can't even see your button or what field you want to duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add an button to your template and define a `@click` function for it, which adds a new item to your `people.phones` array.

Template:

```
<button @click="addNumber">
   add number
</button>
```

Vue:

```
methods: {
   addNumber: function(){
      this.people.phones.push({number: "", type: ""});
   }
}
```

Simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/wpako31u/